# Como integro un archivo de python en PHP

Tags: php, python

Necesito desde php ejecutar un archivo de python, si alguien sabe agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Sin saber mucho de PHP seguro que tiene alguna función tipo `system()` o `command()` o similar que permite ejecutar un programa externo. Basta que le pases como parámetros la ruta al intérprete python y la ruta al script que quieras lanzar. Seguramente tendrá también algún mecanismo para recuperar lo que ese otro comando vuelque en la salida estándar, es decir, lo que el script imprima mediante `print()`.

Comment: Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736494/5587982).